# Using Containable behavior to filter results in Cakephp 2.2.4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using containable behavior and the result of my find('all') is:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '106',
            'email' => 'daje@daje.it',
            'pwd' => '0433c024cb08be13000d59a347e640482843f46f177e95749dc6599c259617fd3491dcb940b47693cbbc7f65a2cc5ef62deca2e600c1be133ad54170f7d1fbd1',
            'role_id' => '3',
            'active' => '1'
        ),
        'Lead' => array(
            'id' => '6'
        ),
        'Estimate' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'lead_id' => '6',
                'Estimate' => array(
                    (int) 0 => array(
                        'TOT_count' => '2'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I need to to count how many estimates there are in the lead.

The total (2) is correct, but i see nested 'Estimated' array, why ?

The result i would like to get is:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '106',
            'email' => 'daje@daje.it',
            'pwd' => '0433c024cb08be13000d59a347e640482843f46f177e95749dc6599c259617fd3491dcb940b47693cbbc7f65a2cc5ef62deca2e600c1be133ad54170f7d1fbd1',
            'role_id' => '3',
            'active' => '1'
        ),
        'Lead' => array(
            'id' => '6'
        ),
        'Estimate' => array(
          'TOT_count' => '2'
        )
    )
)
```

This is the find:

```
$options = array(
                    'contain' => array(
                        'User',
                        'Estimate' => array(
                            'fields' => 'COUNT(*) AS TOT_count'                             
                        )   
                    ),
                    'conditions' => array('Lead.id' => 6),
                    'fields' => 'User.*',                           
                    'limit' => 1

                );

    debug($this->Lead->find('all', $options));
```

How can i do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a "custom" `AS` statement, in your case `TOT_count`, Cake will always put this in a result key called `0`. You can avoid this by defining `TOT_count` as a [virtualField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) in your model. That way it will be nested directly under the model name in your resultset.

Secondly, the `lead_id` is forcedly retrieved, because it is "needed" to make the join with the `Lead` model. It can not properly retrieve all the data without that piece of information there.

Comment: It does not do this whenever you use an `AS` in a find. It does this when you do not use it correctly. [virtualFields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) exist for a reason

Comment: @dogmatic69 D'oh, of course! I've used them before, so I should've remembered. Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer to better reflect the proper way to do it.